# Will Extracting Data From Materialized view Load on Tables During Query Run

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple materialized view which is composed of almost 5 tables. All tables have more than 10 millions records. So instead of querying directly on table i have created a materialized view and refresh daily for reporting purpose.

So my question is that querying from materialized view will put load on our tables? (because directly querying form tables slow our application which depends on these tables), Or would it be a good idea to query on materialized views instead of these tables for reporting purpose?, thanks.

Following is my materialized view.

```
 create materialized view kztl_active_liq_mview
    Refresh Force On Demand
    As

          SELECT     '01-mar-2012'from_date,(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)))to_date, a.Lnu Account_Number, a.Product_Code, a.Amount_Disbursed, (a.Amount_Disbursed-Nvl(B.Amount_Paid,0))Outstaind,
                      DSBR_MAIN_INT, DUE_PRINCIPAL, SETTLED_PRINCIPAL, DUE_MAIN_INT, B.Amount_paid PAID_PRINCIPAL, H.amount_paid PAID_MAIN_INT, NVL(k.od_prp,0)od_prp, 
                      NVL(m.od_sc,0)od_sc, NVL(N.NOT_YET_DUE_PRP,0)NOT_YET_DUE_PRP, p.NOT_YET_DUE_SC,
                      a.Value_Date, a.Maturity_Date, 
                      User_Defined_Status, Branch_Code, Branch_Name, Account_Status, Funding_Source, Sex, Crop
          From
                  (
                   Select   Cam.Customer_Id Cnu, Stc.Unique_Id_Value Cni, Stc.Customer_Name1 Can, Cam.Account_Number Lnu,Cam.Product_Code, 
                            Cam.Amount_Disbursed, Cam.Value_Date, Cam.Maturity_Date, (Cam.Maturity_Date - Cam.Value_Date)  As Lpf_Days,
                            Cam.Branch_Code, Stb.Branch_Name,Cam.Account_Status, Cam.User_Defined_Status, Cam.Field_Char_3 Crop, 
                            Cam.Field_Char_5 Funding_Source, scp.sex
                   From     Cltb_Acct_Master Cam Inner Join Sttm_Customer Stc On
                            Cam.Customer_Id = Stc.Customer_No Inner Join Sttm_Cust_Personal Scp On
                            Cam.Customer_Id = Scp.Customer_No Inner Join Sttm_Branch Stb On
                            Cam.Branch_Code = Stb.Branch_Code
                   Where    Cam.Account_Status in ('A','L')
                   --And      Cam.Value_Date >= '22-sep-2013'
                   And      Cam.Product_Code  In ('KZTL')
                   )A    

                   Left Outer Join 

                   (
                   Select Account_Number, Max(Paid_Date) Paid_Date, NVL(Sum(Amount_Paid),0) Amount_Paid , Component_Name
                   From Cltb_Amt_Paid
                   Where Component_Name = 'PRINCIPAL'
                   And Paid_Date <= (SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)) FROM dual)
                   Group By Account_Number,  Component_Name
                   ) B On A.LNU = B.Account_Number

                   LEFT Outer join
                   (------------------------New1
                   Select Account_Number, NVL(Sum(Amount_Paid),0) Amount_Paid
                   From Cltb_Amt_Paid
                   Where Component_Name  In ('MAIN_INT','PENAL_INT')
                   And Paid_Date <= (SELECT LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-2)) FROM dual)
                   Group By Account_Number
                   )H On A.LNU = H.Account_Number             



    ;
```

Comment: Do you query the materialized view more than once? When you query it only once a day it is quite useless because selecting the base tables takes similar resources as refreshing the materialized view.

Comment: We have day-1 reporting. We daily refresh data at 9:AM daily so that we get the data of last day on daily basis. But my question is different that querying data from materialized view will put load on our tables (because directly querying from tables make our application heavy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the materialized view has been created/refreshed, the tables used to create it will not be effected by queries done on the materialized view - these are seperate objects.
The queries on the materialized view can still create performance issues because heavy queries performed on the materialized view can effect the entire DB in general.

For that reason, it is important to tune the queries done from the MVIEW to the best of your ability, in order to avoid overloading the system.